# `http.get() call wrapped in service returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

I know the http request is working because I receive the data from the server but `$scope.catalogue` is always undefined. I guess because it's assigned before the result comes back from the server. I though I'd taken care of the asynch stuff inside the service?

```
angular.module('catalogue', [])
.factory('Catalogue', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        getCatalogue: function(){
            $http.get('./server.php').then(function(response){
                return response
            });
        },
        setCatalogue: function(JSON){
            $http.post('./server.php', JSON).success(function(){return 'successfully set data'});
        }
    }
}])
```

then in my controller

```
$scope.catalogue = Catalogue.getCatalogue();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the promise:

```
getCatalogue: function(){
    return $http.get('./server.php')
}
```

And in your code you do

```
Catalogue.getCatalogue().then(function(response){
    $scope.catalogue = response;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using angular promise in better way to maintain seperation of concern.
like this:

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
  .service('Github', function($http, $q)
  {
    this.getRepositories = function()
      {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/defunkt')
        .success(function(response)
        {
          // do stuffs with the response
          response.username = response.login + ' ' + response.name;
          // like filtering, manipulating data, decorating data found from from api
          // now pass the response
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(response)
        {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,Github) {
       Github.getRepositories().then(function(dt){
        $scope.user = dt;
       });
  });
```

I just created a plunkr for demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/r7Cj7H